# UICollectionView loading late and scrolling very bumpy

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uicollectionview

I am designing a collection view in which I am trying to load image and text which are stored in a dictionaries in an array. My main array over here i.e the `bannerarray` is being parsed in some other function. But the problem I am having is that my collection view is getting choppy as if it is having bumps on the scrolling road when I am scrolling it to load the images. I have looked for various answers and codes but none has solved my problem.

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LandingPageCVC


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
            {
                let categoryname = self.categoriesarray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("name")

                cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true;
                cell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale



                let imageurl = self.categoriesarray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("image") as! String

                if let url  = NSURL(string: imageurl),
                    data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
                {

                    cell.lndngimage.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
                if indexPath.row % 2 == 0
                {
                    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 67/255.0, green: 179/255.0, blue: 246/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
                }
                else if indexPath.row % 3 == 0 && indexPath.row%2 != 0
                {
                    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
                }
                cell.lndngimg.text = categoryname as? String

        })



        return cell
    }
```

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: is `lndngimg` a textView or `textField` if yes change it to `label`

Comment: `data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)` downloading an image in main thread that's why `UICollectionView` loading late or may be blocking just do one thing create queue for downloading image and set it in main thread.

Comment: Also, you don't need to put these code in dispatch_main(), its already on main queue and layer operations are lengthy many a times. If possible, put those in awakeFromNib of that cell.

Comment: @SunilChauhan Please explain a bit, because I am performing async type. So where is the problem?

Comment: @KamalaDash: Bunty Madan's comment is right: `NSData(contentsOfURL:url)` is downloading the data from server on main thread, blocking the main thread results in sticking the UI. So remove that line and download image asynchronously (i.e. in background thread). For image downloading, I recommend https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage library, which will manage image downloading asynchronously and caches for you as well.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let queue = dispatch_queue_create("loader", nil)
dispatch_async(queue) { () -> Void in
//download the image do stuff
//like data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)

//move back in main thread
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
    //set the image.
    //cell.lndngimage.image = UIImage(data: data)
     })
 }
```

So `data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)` downloading an image in main thread that's why `UICollectionView` loading late or may be blocking just do one thing create queue for downloading image and set it in main thread.

Comment: And what about the scroll?

Comment: yes it work, see the issue is you are doing download in main thread that's you scroll is heavy so just do you downloading stuff in saparte queue and then update UI in main queue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use the NSData(contentsOfURL:) method which loads the images synchronously and block the UI. A asynchronous method like the one provided by AFNetworking would not cause this glitch.

Comment: Please have a look at https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit%2BAFNetworking/UIImageView%2BAFNetworking.h

Comment: Is it possible in AlamoFire,because I am trying to do all stuff in that .

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData(contentsOfURL:url)
```

downloads the image on the main thread, which will block the main thread from updating the UI. You should use a `NSOperation` subclass to download your image. Ray Wenderlich has a [great tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76341/use-nsoperation-nsoperationqueue-swift) on this subject. There are other alternatives you can use such as [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Hope that helps!

EDIT:

As Sunil pointed out above, you don't need to do most of the work in the `dispatch_async` block. The only task you need to do asynchronously is the image download. Make sure you jump back to the main queue when you are ready to update the `UIImageView`